Python PywedgeCharts dataFrame.drop() error
I was trying to use Pywedge_Charts with a csv file (simple csv file with 3 columns ('State', 'Taxes', 'Revenues_year') coding the following:
import pandas as pd
import pywedge as pw

tax = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/XXXX/OneDrive/Documents/Python/Taxes.csv')

viz = pw.Pywedge_Charts(tax, c=None, y='State')

but I get the following error message:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
`your text`Cell In[28], line 1
----> 1 viz = pw.Pywedge_Charts(tax, c=None, y='Taxes')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pywedge\pywedge.py:27, in Pywedge_Charts.__init__(self, train, c, y, manual)
     25 self.c = c
     26 self.y = y
---> 27 self.X = self.train.drop(self.y,1)
     28 self.manual = manual

TypeError: DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tried different things already but I couldn't solve the issue. Any idea how to solve this error?
I am a beginner in Python but this seems a basic code which shouldn't pose problems. Tried assigning another column to y, change csv file but I still encounter the issue.
Thanks in advance

Seeing that the latest version of pywedge was released on Jan 20, 2021, it naturally relies on an old version of df.drop:

df.drop <= 1.4.x
df.drop >= 1.5.x

The old signature:
DataFrame.drop(labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, 
               level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')

The new signature:
DataFrame.drop(labels=None, *, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, 
               level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')

Notice the * in second position in the new signature. This symbol indicates that all arguments that follow must be passed as keyword arguments. See this documentation. In the old version, this * is missing, so that you could write:
df.drop('label', 1)

# meaning: df.drop(labels='label', axis=1)

As you can see from the error message, this is the implementation in pywedge.py:
self.train.drop(self.y,1)

The new version no longer recognizes 1 as the positional argument for axis . Hence, you have to write:
df.drop('label', axis=1)


Solution 1
Downgrade your pandas version to 1.4.4 (or lower).
Solution 2
Locate installed pywedge.py and adjust all the .drop(...) statements. I count four, starting from here. I.e.,
self.X = self.train.drop(self.y,1)

needs to become:
self.X = self.train.drop(self.y, axis=1)


Whether either one of these solutions will solve all issues, is anyone's guess. requirements.txt is unspecific on versions for most dependencies. Hence, both solutions are best combined with a small prayer.

Example
pandas drop function is incorrectly used in the library you used. I'll create a sample to show you why that code is wrong.
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': [59, 11, 65, 95], 'B': [63, 87, 22, 87], 
        'C': [49, 51, 9, 99], 'D': [4, 39, 77, 65]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
    A   B   C   D
0  59  63  49   4
1  11  87  51  39
2  65  22   9  77
3  95  87  99  65

Try deleting the 'A' column from df, and you'll get the same error if you omit the axis parameter.
df.drop('A', 1)

error
TypeError: DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

we can delete column 'A' from df without error if you don't omit the axis parameter.
df.drop('A', axis=1)

It looks like the pywedge library you used is based on an older version of Pandas, which is why it omits the parameter axis in the drop function. I think a proper downgrade of the Pandas version(maybe 1.4.4 based on @ouroboros1's answer) should fix it.
